# I have a problem with substr function(C++)

Tags: c++, function, substring, substr

Well, I am supposed to return the middle character of a word. If the word's length is odd, return the middle character. If the word's length is even, return the middle 2 characters.Like "test" => "es" or "testing" => "t".
And This is what I have wroten =>

```
#include <iostream>
std::string get_middle(std::string input) 
{
  if (input.length() % 2 == 0) {
    return input.substr(1,2);
  } else {
    return input.substr(1,1);
  }
};

int Main() {
  get_middle("test");
  get_middle("testing");
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem you have? Please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Then [edit] your question to include a description of the problem you have, what result you get, what result you expected.

Comment: And a [`substr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr) reference might be good to read as well.

Comment: What is the first argument to `substr`? Why do you always pass `1`, however long the string is?

Comment: `int Main() {` I assume that was a typo since `c++` is case sensitive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your main method is incorrect. Kindly change "Main" to "main" and return some integer value.

This is how you can achieve your task.

```
    #include <iostream>
using namespace std;
std::string get_middle(std::string input)
{
    if (input.length() % 2 == 0) {
        return input.substr((input.length() / 2)-1, 2);
    }
    else {
        return input.substr(input.length()/2, 1);
    }
};
 int main() {
    //cout<<get_middle("test")<<endl;
    cout<<get_middle("testing")<<endl;
    cout << get_middle("test") << endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

t

es

Now first output is for odd string, and second is for even string.

Comment: Thanks man,Your code worked.

Comment: I am glad that you find it useful. Kindly give me thumbs up and accept as answer.

Answer (score 1):

Look at your code, does it return the **middle** character (in either case)? No because you say `input.substr(1,..)` it returns the **second** character.

What you want is this for the odd case

```
return input.substr(input.length()/2, 1);
```

I'll leave you to work out the even case.

In fact if you are very clever about it you can have the same formula for both odd and even cases.

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing the problem is that you are not getting the middle characters (please state the problem next time). The first parameter should be the index of the first character you want in the substring, meaning input.length() / 2